# use same name for two columns in a table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to use same name for two columns with different data type in a single table.

I couldn't use it.

can we use the same name for two columns?

Comment: No, and why would you want to? The column name is its identifier, if it wasn't unique, you wouldn't be able to reference it in any queries. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve that led you to want non-unique names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, column names must be unique to the table (if you're using a database with a case-sensitive collation you can use the same letters for the name as long as they differ in case, which would make the names unique).

You can use the same alias for different columns in your query though, so that you get the impression of having two (or more) columns with the same name:

```
SELECT Column1 AS Column2, Column2 FROM YourTable
```

would give a result like:

```
Column2  Column2
data     data
data     data
```